# SQL Server 2014: apply against xml nodes() function suddenly stops working

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have a stored procedure that suddenly started returning NULL on only one of two supposedly equivalent SQL Server 2014 machines (primary and failover).

The specific operation that is suddenly misbehaving is:

```
    declare @skus TABLE (intSkuId int, attributes xml);
    insert into @skus
    VALUES
        (11443, '<attributes><style>basic_mug</style><color>white</color><size>15oz</size></attributes>'),
        (11444, '<attributes><style>basic_mug</style><color>black</color><size>15oz</size></attributes>');

    select 
        s.intSkuId, s.xmlAttributes,  
        att.query('.') as element 
    from 
        tb_Skus s
    outer apply 
        xmlAttributes.nodes(N'//attributes/*') as atts(att)
    where 
        s.intSkuId = 11443;
```

Note that this would normally be run against a segment of the `tb_Skus` table, not a single value, but I'm simplifying for debugging purposes.

This returns the following result:

```
intSkuId: 11443
xmlAttributes: <attributes><style>basic_mug</style><color>white</color><size>15oz</size></attributes>
element: NULL
```

Note also that the following script works as intended:

```
DECLARE @x xml;

SELECT @x = xmlAttributes 
FROM tb_Skus s 
WHERE s.intSkuId = 11443

SELECT @x AS xmlAttributes, att.query('.') AS element
FROM @x.nodes(N'//attributes/*') AS atts(att)
```

yielding the same value for xmlAttribute, but I get the expected values for element:

```
<style>basic_mug</style>
<color>white</color>
<size>15oz</size>
```

So, is there something wrong with the first query? And if not, are there session or database settings that could alter the behavior of this function?

Comment: While asking a question you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT, T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic, and your attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: ...the binary values should be the same: `select attributes.value('local-name(/*[1])', 'nvarchar(max)'), cast(attributes.value('local-name(/*[1])', 'nvarchar(max)') as varbinary(100)) as xmlbinary, cast(N'attributes' as varbinary(100)) strbinary from tb_Skus where intSkuId = 11443`

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `.nodes()` method in this case. It is needed just when there is a need to convert/shred XML data type into a rectangular/relational data.

Please try the following.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (intSkuId INT, xmlAttributes XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (intSkuId, xmlAttributes) VALUES
(11443,  N'<attributes>
    <style>basic_mug</style>
    <color>white</color>
    <size>15oz</size>
</attributes>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT *
    , xmlAttributes.query('/attributes/*') AS [element]
FROM @tbl
where intSkuId=11443;
```

Comment: I have simplified the query as much as possible, but the reason I am using `.nodes()` here is because I will need to join another table on a function of the `local-name(.)` and the `att.value(N'(.text())[1]', 'nvarchar(50)')`.  The query above gives me a single row with all of the child elements and values; I need each in its own row so that I can compare the values individually (my expected values are in my final `code` block above)

Comment: @JonAgnich, thanks for clarifications. Though (1) from your side is still missing. We need a full repro.

Comment: @JonAgnich, please connect with me on LinkedIn.